# Edit time for Ultimate thread group (jmeter)

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I have prepared a script in jmeter with ultimate thread group setting as start thread count:10, Intial delay:0, Startup Time:10, Hold Load:30, Shutdown:10. I have added aggregate report as listener. When i execute the script, samples# go above 10 for each samples. Does this means more than 10 users are entering.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You will have only 10 (concurrent) users. Jmeter never adds more threads than what we mention in the file.

This is what happening - Once an user finishes the test or a loop, as you had mentioned the test should run for 30 seconds - the same test is repeated again for the user. It will stop automatically after 30 seconds. This is why you might see more than 10 login requests or something similar.

If you do not want your test to behave this way, use Simple thread group and update loop count as 1.

Comment: I have multiple thread groups and want to start these on different time delays. So, i cannot use simple thread group. Is there a way to achieve my scenario, i.e stopping after 40 users using ultimate or stepping up thread group. I will have 40 users on 4 thread groups, each should run all samples from the thread groups only 40 times.